# Tkinter and matplotlib: Bind to FigureCanvasTkAgg to extract curser position in figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to plot a 2d array using matplotlib, and then extract the curser position when I click on the plotted image. Here's a minimal working example of how I would write it:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def callback(event):
    print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

root = Tk()
mf = Frame()

figure = plt.Figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

canvas_wid = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=mf)
canvas_wid.get_tk_widget().pack()   

root.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
mf.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, I don't want to have the coordinates regarding root, but **within the figure**. When I bind the click to mf, the program runs, but clicking doesn't trigger any responde. When I bind it to the Canvas widget - which,to my understanding, would be exactly what I want, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Apparently, Canvas is not a widget when I define it using FigureCanvasTKagg? What structure is needed to extract the cursor position within a figure?

I am fairly new to GUI programming in python and I assume that I am missing a very basic point. I checked the reference manual for tkinter and matpotlib, read plenty of other question, but was not able to find my fallacy.

Comment: Better not to use `Canvas` as variable name as it will hide the tkinter `Canvas` class.

Comment: Changed it in the question, thanks for pointing it out. Also fixed a typo, the error message is of course regarding bind, not pack (as stated previously)

Comment: Still get the error after changing the variable name?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, still same error when changing "root" to "canvas_wid" in the bind.

Comment: Use `canvas_wid.get_tk_widget().bind(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `mpl_connect`. Take a look at [Bind event to click on plot in tkinter canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72098768/291641).

Answer (score 0):

My python version: 3.9

matplotlib version: 3.8.3

the following codes works:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print(matplotlib.__version__)
def callback(event):
    print('the position',event.x,event.y)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=200)

frame.pack()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=70)
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(anchor="nw")
canvas.get_tk_widget().bind('<Button-1>',callback)

root.mainloop()
```