# Bind event to click on plot in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, events

I can bind a click event to a plot (i. e. to print the coordinates that were clicked) like so:

```py
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [2, 3, 1, 4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

def plotClick(event):
   if event.button == MouseButton.LEFT:
      print('Clicked at x=%f, y=%f' %(event.xdata, event.ydata))

plt.connect('button_press_event', plotClick)

plt.show()
```

I'd like to do the same thing with a plot that is contained within a canvas inside a tkinter window like so:

```py
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

window = tk.Tk()
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [2, 3, 1, 4]
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

def plotClick(event):
   if event.button == MouseButton.LEFT:
      print('Clicked at x=%f, y=%f' %(event.xdata, event.ydata))

window.mainloop()
```

What would I have to do to accomplish the same behavior here?

Note: I am aware that one can bind events directly to the canvas using

```py
canvas.get_tk_widget().bind('<Button-1>', plotClick)
```

with

```py
def plotClick(event):
   print('Clicked at x=%f, y=%f' %(event.x, event.y))
```

That however uses pixel coordinates on the canvas instead of the coordinates in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `plt.connect`, use

```py
canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', plotClick)
```

Using this you can access the coordinates in the plot with `event.xdata` and `event.ydata`, but you can also still access the (pixel) coordinates on the canvas using `event.x` and `event.y`.